# How do I align prefixIcon with text on textFormField?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following code for my textFormField:

```
 Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  height: media.height * 0.12,
                  decoration: txtFieldBoxDecoration,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.center,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 26,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      border: InputBorder.none,
                      contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),
                      prefixIcon: const Icon(
                        Icons.email,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: 28,
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Insira seu E-mail',
                      hintStyle: GoogleFonts.openSans(
                          color: Colors.white54, fontSize: 26),
                    ),
                    onChanged: (value) {},
                  ),
                ),
```

And I'm getting the following result: [image]

How do I align the prefix Icon and the hintText like this: [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For align the prefix Icon and the hintText,
You have to remove below code from `InputDecoration`

`contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 14),`

Comment: Thanks @Bhargav Ghodasara, I didn't notice that padding!